# How to change entry-spacing to something like 0.5 with CSL stylesheet ieee-with-url

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, csl

I am using Pandoc with the `--citeproc` command line parameter to generate references using the ieee-with-url CSL stylesheet from here: https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=ieee-with-url:

```
pandoc --from markdown --output main.pdf --standalone --citeproc \
--bibliography=references.bib --csl=ieee-with-url.csl -M reference-section-title:References content.md
```

According to the documentation `entry-spacing` controls the spacing between `bibitems`. The specification only takes integers into account: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/10911/csl-setting-1-5-line-spacing-in-bibliography and is passed on to the target Word/LaTeX/epbub, etc. program to change the desired setting.

I cannot change the value to 0.5 or similar, only integers.

This Markdown

```
Hello, World!

This is a test [@texbook]. This is another test [@latex2e]. Yet this is another
test [@knuth:1984].
```

together with this refences:

```
@book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {\TeX} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

@book{latex2e,
  author = {Leslie Lamport},
  year = {1994},
  title = {{\LaTeX}: a Document Preparation System},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
}

@article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
```

`entry-spacing="0"` gives the following references:

[image]

`entry-spacing="1"` gives the following references:

[image]

For me it's either too little or too much vertical spacing between `bibitems`.

The generation of the bibliography is controlled by this LaTeX template: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex#L349C1-L365C14

```latex
\newlength{\cslhangindent}
\setlength{\cslhangindent}{1.5em}
\newlength{\csllabelwidth}
\setlength{\csllabelwidth}{3em}
\newenvironment{CSLReferences}[2] % #1 hanging-indent, #2 entry-spacing
 {\begin{list}{}{%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
  % turn on hanging indent if param 1 is 1
  \ifodd #1
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\cslhangindent}
   \setlength{\itemindent}{-1\cslhangindent}
  \fi
  % set entry spacing
  \setlength{\itemsep}{#2\baselineskip}}} % <-- changing manually to e.g. 0.5 shold work but cannot change the template
 {\end{list}}
```

Question 1: How to change this setting afterwords, i.e. I cannot change the default template.

Question 2: Is it normal to have 0 `itemsep`/vertical spacing in the bibliography for IEEE stylesheet? It looks little bit compressed to me.

Comment: Regarding your question 2: this is indeed normal, see for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUNpq.png for a screenshot of a random IEEE paper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems for scientific papers this looks okay.